# Why am I getting undefined elevation and population values in my JavaScript async function that uses a geo-location API?

Tags: javascript, api, async-await

I am creating a program which talks to an API to gather information on certain cities. I use two functions, the first which determines the wikiDataId of the city, and then a second, which then determines the elevation and population of the city.
I need to use the wikiDataId in the first function to tell the API which city I need information on. With what I have tried, i get the wikiDataId but then the elevation and population values are undefined. I do not know what I am doing wrong to get the values undefined

```
let userInput = "Bhisho";
let prefix = userInput.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + userInput.slice(1).toLowerCase();

const url = `https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities?   countryIds=ZA&namePrefix=${prefix}`;
const options = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "...",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};

async function myApiFunction() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result.data[0].wikiDataId);

    let url2 = `https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities/${result.data[0].wikiDataId}`;

    async function mySecondApiFunction() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url2, options);
        const result = await response.json();
        console.log(`The elevation above sea level is: ${result.elevationMeters}m`);
        console.log(`The population is: ${result.population} people.`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

    mySecondApiFunction();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

myApiFunction();
```

Comment: You aren't checking whether `response.ok`, so chances are you're getting an error message.